# Receive data sent from loadFile to html page in electron

Tags: jquery, electron

I have `main.js` page where I used `mainWindow.loadFile('./app/main.html',options)` to load new file called main.html

Along with it i sent options which stores data in json structure.

How can I receive and use this `options` data in main.html page?

using loadFile its loading main.html page . How can we retreive the data sent along?

Answer (score 3):

In your HTML page, you must parse the URL of your window

If you sent these options from your main process

```js
mainWindow.loadFile("./app/main.html"), {
  query: { queryKey: "queryValue" },
  hash: "hashValue",
});
```

In your HTML page (renderer process)

```js
console.log(location.href)   // YOUR_PATH/app/main.html?queryKey=queryValue#hashValue
console.log(location.search) // ?queryKey=queryValue
console.log(location.hash)   // #hashValue

// You'll probably want to use URLSearchParams
const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
console.log(params.get("queryKey")) // queryValue
```